# Github Cli command "gh pr create" execution encountered "EOF" in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, command-line-interface, cicd

I tried executing this command in the Terminal(and my environment is Ubuntu22.04) and it worked well with some Loading Effects, but when I configure this command in my docker container(created by my CI/CD pipeline executor) it does not work properly when the CI/CD pipeline runs. Below is my configuration and execution error:

```
      - nsenter --mount=/host/proc/1/ns/mnt sh -c  "cd /home/..USER../Desktop/..PROJECT..&&export https_proxy=..PROXY../&&gh pr create --title "test" --body "test" --base cicd_test"
```

[Error in the CI/CD Console logs which runs properly in the local Terminal with some loading effects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK6yS.png)

hope run properly in the docker or some other alternative command that may work